# Getting jQuery that changes height to do so immediately rather than on a second run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please view the jsfiddle below (sorry for the ugly layout).

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/7hLrLdn2/8/    <---trimmed down version...

If you type into the box and hit Enter, then a div containing your item will be added to the left column. Additionally, a div containing the word "Bands" will be added to the right column.

The red represents the height of the left div. The orange represents the height of the right div.

There is a jQuery function that is meant to match the right div's height with the left div's height. Notice, however, that the right div has a smaller height rather than equal height.

Interestingly, if you type something else and hit enter, you will notice that the right height then matches the left div. So that means the code is working, but on a delayed basis.

How can I get the code to work instantly, so that as soon as you hit enter the *first* time, the right div height equals the left div height?

The definition of the function is under "//Where The Functions Are Defined "

And the place where it is called is under "//Where The Functions Are Called"

Thank you.

JS define

```
$(document).ready(function() {


/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/    
    //Where The Functions Are Defined 


function setMusicHeight(){  
    var UserMusicHeightX = $('#MusicDiv').outerHeight();
    var GenreMusicHeightX = $('#GenreMusicDiv').outerHeight();
```

JS call

```
$('form').submit(function () {


/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/        
            //Where The Functions Are Called 
            setMusicHeight();                 
            setMovieHeight();
            setBookHeight();
```

Comment: This is a timing issue.  Your example is a mess.  Since we can't select movies or books, you could excise those sections completely.  Please trim that down to a minimally coded, reproducible example.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to trim it down. Sorry.

Comment: Side note: You could achieve the same result with just `CSS`. Avoid `Javascript` for this sort of task whenever you can.

Comment: You don't need more than 1 `document ready` event handler. A single one would suffice.

Comment: I've now submitted a trimmed down version, not sure if it's trimmed down enough but I tried. http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/7hLrLdn2/7/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I only see one document ready event handler? "$(document).ready(function() {" only occurs once. If that's what you're referring to.

Comment: `$(function () {});` is a shortcut for it. It's the same as `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: That explains a lot, lol. Thank you.

Comment: While one element is still invisible, its height will return 0. You're sliding up/down some of them and this is probably interfering.

Comment: I've put a call to all your re-sizing functions as a callback to every `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()` and `.slideToggle()`. Then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/7hLrLdn2/10/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that, but that sounds like it would definitely be the problem. I'm looking for fixes now.

Comment: Oh, wow, just saw your fiddle. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `script` is trying to retrieve the elements `height` while they're still being displayed - if they're invisible, the property will return 0, or a smaller number than it should if they're halfway through being totally visible.

The solution is to call your re-sizing `scripts` on the `.fadeIn()` and `.slideToggle()` callbacks, accordingly. You can simplify and call just the necessary ones on each situation.

In general, it would be something like this:

```
function resize() {
    setMusicHeight();
    setMovieHeight();
    setBookHeight();
}

$('#MusicDiv').fadeIn(resize);

.slideToggle(270, resize)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/7hLrLdn2/10/)

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: Elegant solution, surprisingly easy for me to understand, and it works perfectly. MUCH appreciated.